# Override dict square [] operator to perform equality operations

Tags: python, pandas

given data and my own DataFrame class which takes the dict as a parameter like this.

```
frame = {
    "a": ["X4E", "T3B", "F8D", "C7X"],
    "b": [7.0, 3.5, 8.0, 6.0],
    "c": [5, 3, 1, 10],
    "d": [False, False, True, False]
}

df = DataFrame(frame)
```

How would one override the `__getitem__` method for dicts to allow actions such as

```
res = df[(df["b"] + 5.0 > 10.0)]["a"]
```

which would return all the cases where b + 5.0 is greater than 10.0. Like a list/series of booleans. This will eventually extend to something like this

```
res = df[(df["b"] + 5.0 > 10.0) & (df["c"] > 3) & ~df["d"]]["a"]
```

I am not sure how to start with this. I learnt about the `__getitem__` but have no idea how to use this to add a value to values in a dict and perform element wise math ops. This is similar to pandas data frames but not sure how to implement this myself

Comment: To be clear, you aren't trying to do this with pandas, correct? But you are making your own class and want to do this with your new frame class? Is your new class subclassing from anything?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am looking for. No the class doesnt inherit from any other class

Comment: is your new class subclassing from anything currently?

Comment: Nope, the class has no parent or child class

Comment: I'm playing around with this here and it is quickly coming complex and I'm basically just re-inventing a bad version of pandas, which raises the question: why not use pandas? The problem is that in addition to having to do something with `__getitem__()`, you need to make a series class in addition to your frame class so that you can do something like `df['b'] + 5`. You can't do this with a normal list: if you have `[7.0,3.5,8.0,6.0] + 5` you get an error, so you need to make a new `mySeriesClass.__add__()` method, as well, and yea feels like you are recreating pandas now.

Comment: Yeah I have to recreate a smaller version of series and dataframes from pandas that basically fails instead of returning NaN's. I dont have much experience with pandas so no idea how this works underneath. So my DataFrame class will hold a list of Series objects?

Comment: I think so, yes, but again that is quickly getting super complex. Can you better describe what you are trying to do regarding 'failing instead of returning NaNs'? Like what is the case for this and why? You are probably better off either subclassing from pandas and changing one or two things, or probably even just using pandas exactly as is and raising an error outside it. For example, you could use pandas and try whatever code you want and then check if the dataframe contains any NaNs and if it does, raise an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a super simplified, but you'll need to define `__getitem__` on your `DataFrame` class and also have some type of `Column` (similar to `pd.Series` in pandas).

Right now this only implements the `__add__`, but to get where you want to go, you'll need to implement the other comparison operators (and check the types of your `Column`s) as well as some indexing mechanism. Hope this helps a bit!

```py
class Column:
    def __init__(self, l):
        self.l = l

    def __str__(self):
        return f"<Column {self.l}>"

    def __add__(self, o):
        return Column([n + o for n in self.l])


class DataFrame:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = {}

        for key, val in data.items():
            if isinstance(val, list):
                self.data[key] = Column(val)

    def __str__(self):
        s = "<DataFrame\n"

        for key, val in self.data.items():
            s += f"\t{key}: {val}\n"

        s += ">"

        return s

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.data[key]


frame = {
    "a": ["X4E", "T3B", "F8D", "C7X"],
    "b": [7.0, 3.5, 8.0, 6.0],
    "c": [5, 3, 1, 10],
    "d": [False, False, True, False],
}


df = DataFrame(frame)

print(df)
print(df["b"])
print(df["b"] + 5.0)
```

**Output**

```
<DataFrame
    a: <Column ['X4E', 'T3B', 'F8D', 'C7X']>
    b: <Column [7.0, 3.5, 8.0, 6.0]>
    c: <Column [5, 3, 1, 10]>
    d: <Column [False, False, True, False]>
>
<Column [7.0, 3.5, 8.0, 6.0]>
<Column [12.0, 8.5, 13.0, 11.0]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if your question is about dictionaries or dataframes... But for dicts I would go about it like this:

get the value of "b" which is a list in your example,
iterate through list and if value + 5 is greater than 10 return true, else return false.

This code should work:

```
for x in range(len(frame["b"])):
    if frame["b"][x] + 5 > 10:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")
```

Apologies if I have misunderstood what you were asking for.